# finding Login/Password for Sybase DB/Coldfusion code

Tags: coldfusion, sybase, coldfusion-9

I have a application CF-9 with Sybase database as back end.I was recently given this legacy code. 
I do not have access to the Test/Prod environment.
So placed the code on my local Desktop Machine.

The code is in the following manner vis a vis DB/Name/Username/Password

The "applcation.cfm" uses an alias for the db

```
<CFSET dsnApp="33ERYD_9S">
```

and all the  tags use "name/datasource", but no "Username/Password" attributes.

```
<cfquery name="delGoods" datasource="#dsnApp#">
                 DELETE FROM goods_table where goodsTable_ID='#goodId#'
             </cfquery>
```

My team lead **insisted that "password/Login" for Sybase-DB  is in the CF code.**
I searched throughly , but did not find any "password/Login" for Sybase-DB.

I told her that since  tags do not  use "Username/Password" attributes, the password/Login must be set in the Coldfusion Administratar.

**any suggestions where else should I look for the "password/Login" for Sybase-DB.?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree with you that the settings are defined in the datasource definition in the CF Administrator.

The different public frameworks will often have configuration files that could store commonly used variables like a datasource username and password however you would see signs of this in the code eg `datasource="#getDatasourceName#" username="#getDatasourceUser#"...`

The final option, although unlikely, is that if this application uses CF-ORM there could be a hibernate configuration file - however if orm was in use you probably wouldn't see the `cfquery` tags anyway.

You might need to go back to the team lead and get some background on the development of the current code base to find out why shey thinks the values are in the code - has that module been removed from the app, is it in a different branch, etc

Answer (score 2):

CF 9 or 9.0.1?

if you using CF 9, maybe this post can help you: 
http://paulalkema.com/post.cfm/pull-a-list-of-all-coldfusion-datasources-along-with-username-and-passwords

Comment: I do not have access to the Test/Prod environment.
So placed the code on my local Desktop Machine.